# Apple Compressor's distributed processing for Autodesk Maya

Tags: terminal, bash, compressor

Is there a way to render Autodesk Maya 2017 animation via `Compressor 4.3` using 10 iMacs?

It was possible in previous versions of Compressor (version 2, version 3 and up to version 4.0.7) There were `Qmaster` and `Qadministrator` utilities. But I can't run Compressor 4.0.7 or those utilities on macOS 10.12.

A distributed processing is necessary feature for any command line VFX professional application. For instance: *Nuke, Shake, Fusion, Maya, Houdini, Renderman, etc...*

I am convinced, there is a workaround to use the distributed processing for CLI applications via Terminal (even if this feature is not explicitly supported in `Compressor 4.3` GUI).

**P.S. Distributed processing isn't supported in Compressor's GUI since 2013 (from v4.1).** Compressor's versions 4.1, 4,2 and 4.3 have `integrated Qmaster`'s core allowing to process just Final Cut Pro X and Motion batches using shared computers (as instances). Now Compressor is mainly used for transcoding.

[image]

Look at `Qmaster.framework` located in:

```
/Applications/Compressor/Contents/Plugins/Compressor/CompressorKit.bundle/Contents/Frameworks
```

To see a list of CLI commands, type this in Terminal:

```
/Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/MacOS/Compressor -help
```

Comment: Does this help?: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21243?locale=en_US.  Note that batch processing is supported but true distributed processing isn’t (IIRC, beginning with Compressor 4, Apple scrapped Qmaster)

Comment: I read it, thank you. The question is: what's the workaround?

Comment: From what I can tell, there is no workaround for true distributed processing on MacOS. (I have done this same research pretty exhaustively.) My only thought would be Pooch. See these two links: http://daugerresearch.com/pooch/parallelapps.shtml, http://daugerresearch.com/pooch/quicktime.shtml. Also see the “About Pooch” pages.

Comment: You're right, Qmaster in Compressor 4.3 is suitable for transcoding only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a thorough research I found out that it's impossible to use Apple Compressor 4.3 via command line for distributed processing.